# Call value from another table based on a column value

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have two tables as shown below

```
table 1
-------   
type_id   type_title
=======   ===========
      1   Zoning District  
      2   Parcel_ID  
      3   CC Districts


table 2
-------   
location _id  type_id   store_value
============  =======   ===========
        6846        1   E - Big South  
        6846        2   L3300
        6846        3
```

I would like to display the following output

```
location_id  Parcel_ID  Zoning_Districts  CC_Districts
===========  =========  ================  ============
       6846  L3300      E - Big South
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and use conditional aggregation:

```
select t2.location_id,
  max(case when t1.type_title = 'Parcel_ID' then t2.store_value end) Parcel_ID,  
  max(case when t1.type_title = 'Zoning District' then t2.store_value end) Zoning_Districts,
  max(case when t1.type_title = 'CC Districts' then t2.store_value end) CC_Districts  
from table2 t2 left join table1 t1
on t1.type_id = t2.type_id
group by t2.location_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WQ5FKqMt8eELAhUecavAb/1).
Results:

```
| location_id | Parcel_ID | Zoning_Districts | CC_Districts |
| ----------- | --------- | ---------------- | ------------ |
| 6846        | L3300     | E - Big South    |              |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with location_cte
AS(
SELECT DISTINCT locationId
FROM table2
)
SELECT locationId,
(Select store_value FROM table2 t Where t.locationId = c.locationId And typeId =2),
...
...
...
FROM location_cte c
```

You need fetch all distinct location from table 2 then for each column have a query.